# Joining Multiple Large Tables

Tags: sql, sybase

I have three tables

```
Table T1: Columns {a,b,c}, combination {a,b} is unique in Table T1
Table T2: Columns {a,c,d}, combination {a,c} is unique in Table T2
Table T3: Columns {a,c,e}, combination {a,c} is unique in Table T3
```

where {a,b,c} are strings and {d,e} are numbers

I want my output to be

```
Table T4: Columns {a,b} where e/d < x.
```

Tables T1,T2,T3 are all very large (millions of rows), so the way I implemented this is by doing an left join on table T1 T2 and saving the results to a temp table, then doing an left join on tables T1 T3 and saving the results, then doing an left join of the results and finally combining these temp tables into 1 final table.

My question is, is there a better/more efficient way to do this without blowing up the database?

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just doing this the straight-forward way?

```
select t1.a, t1.b
into t4
from t1
join t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.c = t2.c
join t3 on t1.a = t3.a and t1.c = t3.c
where t3.e / t2.d < x
```

Storing millions of records in temp tables isn't good for performance or storage...

Comment: I agree with this, unless the OP's database is very undersized for his storage requirements, this should work fine.

Comment: So, perhaps I don't understand enough SQL, but a join does the cartesian product (so if i have two tables one with 10 rows and one with 10MM rows, it'll create a table of 100MM rows and do elimination).  No?

Comment: Not if you are joining on keys. Cartesian product only occurs when you aren't joining on keys. in your example, if you have a FK on the 10mil row table as a PK from the 10 row table, then you just have 10mil rows returned, with the data from the 10 row table included in the result set.

Comment: You are filtering on both T2 and T3. A left join doesn't make sense since you are using data from both tables.

Comment: Last question:  If I'm now joining on more than 2 (large) tables, is it better to to just keep adding join clauses instead of trying to use temp tables?